# How to authenticate Vue.js / Axios request of an API route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, axios

I'm in Laravel 5.6. I have all my API routes built out and properly responding to requests from my REST client (Paw). I'm trying to build a simple front end to access those routes.

I'm trying to use Laravel's out-of-the-box features as much as possible, so I'm using Axios to call those routes from a blade template using Vue.js. It works if I disable auth middleware on the test route, but I get 401 errors on the console when auth middleware is enabled for the route.

The problem seems obvious enough... The `auth:api` guard on my `/api` routes wants to see an oauth token in the header, but when I log in with the web page it does session authentication. I assume there's a simple way to resolve this without having to spoof an oauth token request in the web frontend, right? Do I need to somehow pass the session token in my request with Axios? And, if so, do I also need to change the `auth:api` guard in my api routes file?

Comment: By default `auth:api` middleware requires each user to have a field in the database called `api_token`, did you add one?

Comment: That's not really the issue here. Passport created a field in the `user` table called `remember_token` and my API routes are all working properly with OAuth from my REST client. The issue is consuming those same API routes from the Vue.js / Axios front end I'm trying to build.

Comment: Ah, so you have the token in the frontend, but are not sure on how to attach it to the request?

Comment: I seem to have broken something now. I'm now only getting `undefined` back from Axios, even when I disable all auth. Notably, I see a 404 error in the console for `/js/bootstrap.js.map`. Searches for that issue bring back a million hits, but no working answers.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the thing that broke the whole script. I still get the 404 error int he console about `/js/bootstrap.js.map`, but that doesn't seem to matter because I get the desired result when I disable auth on the route. So I'm back to where I was when I first posted this question and still don't have a working solution.

Comment: the `.map` file is purely for debugging purposes, it giving a `404` should **not** impact the script in any way

Answer (score 12):

I solved it! I'm a bit embarrassed because the answer was actually in the Laravel docs, but I will say I tried this before posting the question here and it wasn't working. Perhaps something else was broken at the time.

Per the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript):

> All you need to do is add the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware to your
>   `web` middleware group in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:
>
> ```
> 'web' => [
>     // Other middleware...
>     \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
> ],
> ```
>
> This Passport middleware will attach a `laravel_token` cookie to your
>   outgoing responses. This cookie contains an encrypted JWT that
>   Passport will use to authenticate API requests from your JavaScript
>   application. Now, you may make requests to your application's API
>   without explicitly passing an access token...

Comment: In addition to this, I also had to call `Passport::withoutCookieSerialization()` from within my `AppServiceProvider`s `boot` method. More information can be found [in these Laravel upgrade notes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.30)

Comment: This helped me https://pineco.de/laravel-api-auth-with-tokens/

Answer (score 7):

You will probably want to use [Larvel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport) or a JWT auth mechanism for obtain the `Authorization` token.

Seeing as how you're using axios, add a request interceptor to attach the access token to every request once you successfully authenticate. A simple example:

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // assume your access token is stored in local storage 
    // (it should really be somewhere more secure but I digress for simplicity)
    let token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    if (token) {
       config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
    }
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

to use the `auth:api` first you need `api_token` inside your users table

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('api_token', 80)->after('password')
                        ->unique()
                        ->nullable()
                        ->default(null);
});
```

also you can create a user for testing as follows

```
User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'api_token' => Str::random(60),
    ]);
```

in your layout use the following before `@yield('content')`

```
<script>
     window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode(['api_token' => (Auth::user())->api_token]); ?>
</script>
```

now you can use window.laravel.api_token inside your vue js to use it in headers

heres an example

```
var methods = new Vue({
    el: '#tabs_lists',
    data: {
        config: {
            headers: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + window.Laravel.api_token,
              Accept: 'application/json'
            }
           },
        data: []
    },
    methods: {
        test: function (link) {
            axios.get(link, this.config)
               .then(response => (this.data = response.data)).catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
    }
}
  )
```